# What IAM role should be assigned to aws lambda function so that it can get the emr cluster status

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-emr

I've prepared a simple lambda function in AWS to terminate long running EMR clusters after a certain threshold is reached. This code snippet is tested locally and is working perfectly fine. Now I pushed it into a lambda, took care of the library dependencies, so that's also fine. This lambda is triggered from a CloudWatch rule, which is a simple cron schedule. I'm using an existing IAM rule which has these 7 policies attached to it.

- SecretsManagerReadWrite
- AmazonSQSFullAccess
- AmazonS3FullAccess
- CloudWatchFullAccess
- AWSGlueServiceRole
- AmazonSESFullAccess
- AWSLambdaRole

I've configured the lambda to be inside the same vpc and security group as that of the emr(s). Still I'm getting this error consistently:

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the ListClusters operation: User: arn:aws:sts::xyz:assumed-role/dev-lambda-role/terminate_inactive_dev_emr_clusters is not authorized to perform: elasticmapreduce:ListClusters on resource: *: ClientError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/terminate_dev_emr.py", line 24, in terminator
ClusterStates=['STARTING', 'BOOTSTRAPPING', 'RUNNING', 'WAITING']
File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 314, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 612, in _make_api_call
raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the ListClusters operation: User: arn:aws:sts::xyz:assumed-role/dev-lambda-role/terminate_inactive_dev_emr_clusters is not authorized to perform: elasticmapreduce:ListClusters on resource: *
```

My lambda function looks something like this:

```
import pytz
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def terminator(event, context):
    ''' cluster lifetime limit in hours '''
    LIMIT = 7
    TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
    AWS_REGION = 'eu-west-1'

    print('Start cluster check')

    emr = boto3.client('emr', region_name=AWS_REGION)

    local_tz = pytz.timezone(TIMEZONE)
    today = local_tz.localize(datetime.today(), is_dst=None)
    lifetimelimit = today - timedelta(hours=LIMIT)

    clusters = emr.list_clusters(
        CreatedBefore=lifetimelimit,
        ClusterStates=['STARTING', 'BOOTSTRAPPING', 'RUNNING', 'WAITING']
    )

    if clusters['Clusters'] is not None:
        for cluster in clusters['Clusters']:
            description = emr.describe_cluster(ClusterId=cluster['Id'])
            if(len(description['Cluster']['Tags']) == 1 
                and description['Cluster']['Tags'][0]['Key'] == 'dev.ephemeral'):
                print('Terminating Cluster: [{id}] with name [{name}]. It was active since: [{time}]'.format(id=cluster['Id'], name=cluster['Name'], time=cluster['Status']['Timeline']['CreationDateTime'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
                emr.terminate_job_flows(JobFlowIds=[cluster['Id']])

    print('cluster check done')

    return
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As error message indicates, lambda does not have permissions to call ListClusters on EMR. As you are working with EMR clusters and would also like to terminate the clusters, you should give lambda function proper IAM role which is having that capability to do that. Create a new IAM policy from AWS console (say EMRFullAccess). here is how it looks like

```
 {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "elasticmapreduce:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

After creating policy, create a new role from AWS console with lambda as service and attach newly created policy above. After that, attach this role to your lambda function. That should solve issue :-)

Comment: Thanks. Actually I added an EMR Admin policy to an existing role that was attached to my lambda. But underlying idea was the same as yours. It resolved the issue.